# Assign uitableview cell based on dictionary valueForKey

Tags: ios, uitableview, nsarray, nsdictionary

I have a dictionary with valueForKey:@"point" and valueForKey:@"name". Only "name" is displayed in the tableview. When it populates the tableview I want to set each cell color according to the "point" value it has. This is dependent on how far off the "point" is from a 'total' value.

So, I start with setting the 'total' value by generating an array of objects, let's say "fruit", and take a count of the total objects in the array. Again, I want to compare how far off "point" is from that total number. Based on that difference:
-if it matches, make the cell color blue 
-if it is one number less, make it green
-if it is two numbers less, make it red...

```
    NSArray *fruit = [fruits valueForKey:@"fruitName"];

    //total number of fruit
    int equal = fruit.count;
    NSString *isEqual = [@(equal) stringValue];
    NSArray *isEqual2 = [isEqual componentsSeparatedByString:@""];

    //total number of fruit minus one
    int minusOne = fruit.count -1;
    NSString *minusOne1 = [@(minusOne) stringValue];
    NSArray *minusOne2 = [minusOne1 componentsSeparatedByString:@""];

    //creating array of "point" from dictionary
    NSArray *pointsArray = [self.points valueForKey:@"point"];

        if ([pointsArray containsObject:isEqual]) {
            cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
        }
        else if ([pointsArray containsObject:minusOne2]){
            cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
        }
```

It doesn't enter the statements to color the cells. 
When I log 'pointsArray' I get the array (e.g. 4,1,1,1...).
When I log 'isEqual' I get the totalFruit number (e.g. 4).

I've also tried `isEqualToArray` with no luck. How can I assign each cell color?

Comment: What are the objects in pointsArray? Are they NSNumbers or strings?

Comment: Sorry I'm a newbie, and not exactly sure. In creating the "point" I use: 'pointExpDesc.name = @"point"; pointExpDesc.expression = rankExpresion; pointExpDesc.expressionResultType = NSInteger64AttributeType;' and when I print it I get '<__NSArrayI 0x7b7bbee0>(4,3,1,1...)'.

Comment: Report what this log gives you, NSLog(@"%@",[pointsArray[0]  class])

Comment: Your code really doesn't make sense for what you say you're trying to accomplish. If the array is {4,3,1,1..) and equal = 4, then that array contains both equal (4) and minusOne (3). That doesn't seem like what you want to do. Also, I have no idea what you're doing with componentsSeparatedByString -- there's nothing to separate, isEqual is a single character (and passing @"" to that method doesn't make sense anyway). I don't know what a _PFCachedNumber is, but I assume it's a number that you can convert to an int and compare with equal, which is what you need to do.

Comment: With your help I managed to change 'isEqual' to an NSNumber. It now recognizes when first cell is equal or minus one and changes all cells to that color. Any ideas on how to specify only that cell rather than all?

Answer (score -1):

Replace `([pointsArray containsObject:isEqual])` with:

```
([pointsArray containsObject:[isEqual stringValue]])
```

And replace `([pointsArray containsObject:minusOne2])` with:

```
([pointsArray containsObject:[minusOne2 stringValue]])
```

Comment: This is incorrect. Neither of your suggestions will compile. isEqual is a string, and NSString doesn't have a stringValue method. Neither does NSArray, which is what minusOne2 is.

Comment: No luck, I get 'No visible @interface for 'NSString' declares the selector 'stringValue'. Any other ideas?

Comment: ohh.. I got confuse. What is the type of objects in the array? Check the type of object in pointsArray.